# Enable Swipe to Delete Only when certain segment is selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, edit, swipe

I want only the cells displayed when segmentedcontrol.segmentindex == 7.

With the below code every cell regardless of segment selected is "swipe deletable" by default.

I have an if statement to check for segment selected but it doesn't seem to change the results.

I have also attempted other solutions that check for an indexpath before enabling editing, no luck with any of those.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    editingStyle = UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;

    if(!_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 7){
        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex);
        editingStyle = UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    }

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        _MyTeamArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myTeam"]];

        [_MyTeamArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        NSLog(@" Pre-remove %@",_MyTeamArray);

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_MyTeamArray forKey:@"myTeam"];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Unhandled editing style! %ld", editingStyle);
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you want to use the `- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` function of the `UITableViewDataSource` instead. The implementation could be as simple as `return _segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 7;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 7)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing my comment to an answer:

You probably want to use the `- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` function of the `UITableViewDataSource` instead. The following implementation maybe all you need (provided there isn't more complex logic than you presented.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPat {
    return _segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 7;
}
```